# switching npm registry based on directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently started developing for node. The company that I work for has an internal npm registry. I want to know how to use different registry settings depending upon where I am developing. To illustrate, I have a directory structure like shown below:

```
~/Code
|
| -- My Projects
| |
| | -- Proj 1 
| | -- Proj 2
|
|-- My Company
  |
  |--Proj 1 
  |--Proj 2
```

When I am developing in one of the projects in 'My Project', I would like the npm registry to point to https://registry.npmjs.org (the default registry). But when I am developing in one of the projects in 'My Company', I want npm registry to point to the company specific registry. Right now, my naive method is to use 
`npm config set registry` to update the registry.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are two distinct use cases for using your private npm registry:

1. **Installing:** use the `--reg` or `--registry` flag:

   ```
   npm install mypackage --reg http://myreg.npmjitsu.com
   ```
2. **Publishing:** you can also use `--reg` or `--registry`, but I would highly recommend that you use the `publishConfig` setting in your `package.json` file (See: [the npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#publishconfig))

   ```
   {
     "publishConfig": {
       "registry": "http://myreg.npmjitsu.com"
     }
   }
   ```

   *This prevents developers from accidentally publishing private modules to the public registry by forgetting the `--registry` flag*

So add `publishConfig` to all of the `package.json` for your Company use `--registry` when installing from their private npm.

Comment: thanks im thinking its a good design to have the --reg flag on npm commands. Does this flag work on other commands too? like npm search / npm update?

Comment: What happens when you put your private package into your package.json?

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4751

npm recently added support for per-package .npmrc files, should do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Registry should only be needed when you're installing packages.  You can use this when you wish to install from the private registry.

```
npm install packagename --registry https://myregistryurl
```

This may work too..

```
npm install https://myregistryurl/packagename
```

and just install the normal way when you're using the public registry.

Answer (score 2):

Create `.npmrc` file in your project directory with following content

```
registry=http://localhost:4873/ # url of your company registry
```

[npmrc Files documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#npmrc-files)